# how to the svg water fill dynamic in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

here's the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cyqdzy?file=src/app/app.component.ts

***html***

***typescript***

```
data = [
  {
    name: 'server1',
    humidity: '50.9'
  },
  {
    name: 'server2',
    humidity: '52.9',
  },
  {
    name: 'server3',
    humidity: '53.9',
  }
]
  humidityPercentage: any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {


    for (let x = 0; x <= this.data.length; x++) {
      this.humidityPercentage = this.data[x].humidity + '%';
    }
  }
```

there's 3 item then what I want to do here is to make it dynamic for example the first item/water 50.9 then it will display on the first item if the second is 52.9 then it should 52.9.

the error is here is it will get the last data, it will not display based on the index.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend adding a pipe to make the code cleaner

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'humidityPipe'
})
export class HumidityPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return  value + '%' ;
  }

}
```

and then you can use :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data;let i = index">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" viewbox="0 0 30 42" aria-hidden="true"
    attr.fill="url(#color-{{i}})">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="color-{{i}}" x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="0%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgb(132, 219, 255)" />
            <stop [attr.offset]="item.humidity | humidityPipe" stop-color="rgb(132, 219, 255)" />
            <stop [attr.offset]="item.humidity | humidityPipe" stop-color="rgb(255, 255, 255)" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgb(255, 255, 255)" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <g transform="translate(35,65)">
        <path id="scale" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" d="M15 3
                            Q20.5 12.8 40 35
                            A28.8 28.8 0 1 1 0 30
                            Q20.5 12.8 15 3z" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

p.s. If you use `<defs>` tags, remember to use an id for each definition, otherwise you will always use the same filling!

I added a stackblitz for you:

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymupuk

Comment: can you create on stackblitz?

Comment: I added a stackblitz for you !

Comment: The pipe 'humidityPipe' could not be found ("00%" x2="0%" y2="0%">
<stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgb(132, 219, 255)" />
<stop [ERROR ->][attr.offset]="data.humidity | humidityPipe" stop-color="rgb(132, 219, 255)" />
<stop")

Comment: Add humidityPipe to your app.module in declarations !